# Find object keys when value is an object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the Object.keys(object1).find(key=> object1[key] === x)
Where x is an object:

```
let x = {
  name: "Test"
  id: 1
  }
```

The goal is to return b, because that's the corresponding key to the object x, but I can't compare x to the object within object1, because objects don't easily compare. How would I go about to include one of the solutions from the following post, inside the "Object.keys(object1).find..." function? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

I have the following object:

```
let object1 = {
  a: "123"
  b: {
     name: "Test"
     id: 1
     }
  c: {
     name: "John"
     id: 2
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In JS: **`{} !== {}`**! You should make a function that compares two object key by key!

Comment: No, ES6 does not have any function to compare objects by their property values.